# Show Action via iron:router, template isn't passed data from a collection.findOne method

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router

I can't get a the 'show' page of an instance of a model to display its data.

Here's the template that won't show its data:

```
<template name="priority">
  <h1>Priority: {{title}}</h1>
</template>
```

It's very simple in and of itself, yet I can't get *title* to display. Iron:router does the job of directing us to this page with the following code:

```
Router.route('/priority/:_id', function(){
  var priority = this.params._id; 
  this.render('priority', {
    data: function(priority){
      Meteor.call('showPriority', priority, function(error){
        if (error) {
          console.log("An error has occured: " + error); 
        }
      })
    }
  })
},  {
  name: 'priority.show'
});
```

The Meteor.method is very simple, it just queries for the variable *priority*:

```
'showPriority': function(priority) { 
    return Priorities.findOne({_id: priority});
  }
```

The view which carries the href is here:

```
<template name="priorityList">
  <ul class="table-view">
    {{#each this}}
    <li class="table-view-cell">
      {{title}}
      <a href="{{pathFor route="priority.show"}}"><span class="pull-right icon icon-edit"></span></a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Note that this view shows a list of all **priorities**. When I inspect the href, all the paths are being dynamically generated with an `_id`:

```
<a href="/priority/yYihyZmZ2xkAso7i5">...
```

Oh, and I should mention, that I also tried to use the `waitOn` method, since I thought I might be loading the template before the data, but that didn't help either...

```
Router.configure({
  ...
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('priorities');
  }
});
```

So much code, just to show what's going on!

What's the deal here? Why won't my "show" template give me any data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you route to this.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('priority', {
    path: '/priority/:_id',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe('priorities',this.params._id);
    },
    data: function(){
      if(this.ready()){
         return Priorities.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
       }else{
        this.render('loading') //if data not ready we render some loading template
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You don't need to make a Meteor.call, for the `find();` instead to everything on the `data:function()`

The above is just an example so you can get the idea, but it should work since you are expecting `_id:priority` and `_id:this.params._id` its the same.

Just be sure you have the **autopublish package removed**.

and have the `subscriptions/publish` in order.

```
Meteor.publish('Menu', function(){
          return Priorities.find();
        });
```

Comment: 'showPriority': function(priority) { 
    return Priorities.findOne({name: 'priority.show'});
  } 

Was what I tried in my Meteor.methods object. My template still didn't render the title of a priority =(

Comment: stuck at my job, going to try this at home soon